# Хороший способ прохода по папкам для поиска файла

Tags: c++, qt5, qt, c++11

Здравствуйте. У меня рядом с экзешником лежит папка plugins, в которой лежат плагины, каждый в отдельной папке, причем имя папки совпадает с именем плагина. Так вот, мне нужно получить список всех этих плагинов. Сам я делаю так:

```
QDir pluginsDir = QDir::current();
pluginsDir.cd("plugins");
for(const QString& dir : pluginsDir.entryList(QDir::Dirs | QDir::NoDotAndDotDot)) {
    //Это так получаю имя файла
    QString pluginName = pluginsDir.absolutePath() + "/" + dir +"/" + dir + ".dll";
    /* ... */
}
```

Тут pluginsDir.entryList(...) вернет список всех папок.
Возник вопрос: есть ли какой-нибудь другой способ получить список всех плагинов?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

а чем данный метод не подходит? Его можно немножко улучшить, использовав std::transform (или подобное). Вот [пример кода](http://lord-baskervil.livejournal.com/33913.html).

**Обновление**

А что Вам нужно, скорость? красота кода? что то ещё?

если скорость - то в любом случае упираетесь в файловую систему. Но пока плагинов будет десяток-другой, все будет достаточно быстро. На будущее можно сделать кеширование списка. А это будет сильное ускорение.

Красота кода - это уже другое. Возможно даже нужно создать спецкласс, который по имени плагина возвращал его имя (кешируя внутри при необходимости).

Comment: Не кажется он мне эффективным. А за ссылку спасибо, почитаю

Comment: @KoVadim, не уверен, что кэширование списка плагинов может существенно ускорить обработку в целом, поскольку при обращении к плагину (dlopen()) само ядро все равно будет читать тот же файл каталога.

Comment: Спасибо, тогда оставлю как есть:)

Answer (score 1):

В своё время я получил солидный выигрыш по скорости, когда отказался от `entryList` и перешёл на [`QDirIterator`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qdiriterator.html).
Правда, это было на каталоге с 1000+ файлов.